How to add AppendInnerLoop method to Autocad using Python?
Inputs:
layers_points = https://pastebin.com/raw/YHmSSLp8
all_cycles = https://pastebin.com/raw/bXFqyqaR
The task is to create cycles on coordinates from all_cycles and add hatches on them. My code accomplishes this task, but there is a problem. There is a cycle A that is inside a cycle B. I need to find these two cycles and apply the AppendInnerPoint method to them so that the hatching of cycle B does not overlap cycle A.
Example for AppendInnerLoop method:
in_loop = []
in_loop.append(acadModel.AddPolyline(ADouble(cycle))
inner = variants(in_loop)
hatch.AppendInnerLoop(inner)


Now the hatching is done like this:

It needs to be done like this:

Here is the code that performs the original functionality:
import win32com.client
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

layer_points = [...]

all_cycles = [...]

acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
acadModel = acad.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace 

def ADouble(xyz):
    return win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_R8, (xyz))

def variants(object):
    return win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_DISPATCH, (object))


polygons = [Polygon(zip(cycle[::3], cycle[1::3])) for cycle in all_cycles]
added_areas = set()

for idx, points in enumerate(layer_points):
    for point in points:
        point_coords = point[:2]
        hatch_texts = point[2:]
        point_shapely = Point(*point_coords)
        for i, polygon in enumerate(polygons):
            if polygon.contains(point_shapely) and i not in added_areas:
                for cycle in all_cycles:
                    if cycle == all_cycles[i]:
                        out_loop = [acadModel.AddPolyline(ADouble(cycle))]
                        for text in hatch_texts:
                            hatch = acadModel.AddHatch(0, 'ANSI37', True)
                            hatch.AppendOuterLoop(variants(out_loop))
                            hatch.Evaluate()
                            hatch.Color = 6
                            added_areas.add(i)
                break

